# How to remove spaces from the url in Django

Tags: python, django, url

How can I remove spaces or any non-alpha-numeric characters from the URLs in Django?

My urls.py looks like this.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(P?<query>^\d+:[a-z]+)/show$', views.results, name='results')
]
```

I want to remove if there is space in the queries like ("/12:some query/show") and fire the query as ex("/12:somequery/show")

Comment: Rewrite the url? Or just fire the view with a slighlty modified `query`?

Comment: rewriting the url ..  Is it possible to do anything in the urls.py itself ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess one simpler solution could be parsing `query` in your views before fetching the object and replacing space there.

for example in your views.py:

```
# If class based
def get_object(self):
    query = self.kwargs.get('query', '')
    query = query.replace(' ', '')
    ....

# If using function based
query = request.GET.get('query', '')
query = query.replace(' ', '')
....
```

Comment: Thanks Reza, it is class based. how do I call ```get_object``` and recall the page after removing the spaces. I am new to Django.